# XAML ListView Data Bind To DateTime

Tags: xaml

In my ViewModel I have a

```
public ObservableCollection<DateTimeOffset> notOnDates
{
    get => _notOnDates;
    set => SetProperty(ref _notOnDates, value);
}
```

How do bind a ListView control to the ViewModel notOnDates?

```
ItemsSource="{x:Bind viewModel.notOnDates, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate x:DataType="x:Object">
          <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Converter={StaticResource offConverter}}" />
       </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

This line is throwing "object not supported in UWP"

```
 <DataTemplate x:DataType="x:Object">
```

The designer shows markup error but the project builds and runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the element of `ObservableCollection` is `DateTimeOffset`, you could pass `"system:DateTimeOffset"` to `x:DataType`.

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="system:DateTimeOffset">
        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Converter={StaticResource DateConverter}}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```